# Verifying custom Qsys component?

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, verification

A *Qsys* system has to be generated to create all the source files for simulation and synthesis. Here it shall create copies of the primary *RTL* source files of custom components also.

These copies shall exist inside the simulation and synthesis folders inside the *Qsys* system directory, I never figured out why it has to create local copies.

If I am running a simulation, I would tend to modify the *RTL* file continuously, recompile it and rerun the simulation. This is just how development and debugging is done in general.

However, how will it work with *Qsys*? Do I really have to regenerate the *Qsys* system every time, so the source file in the simulation folder is updated before I restart and rerun the simulation?

Do I misunderstand how *Qsys* custom component verification is to be carried out?

Comment: Is this when you are debugging your own RTL that interfaces with the QSys blocks or when you are debugging the generated QSys blocks to see if you got the parameters correctly?

Comment: Just edit the file in the simulation folder and then copy it back to your IP directory when done.

Comment: DonFusili, this is when debugging my own RTL to verify that it does the right things in the Qsys system. This basically involves verifying that the Avalon-MM interfaces correctly latch input and write output.

Comment: Do you script your synthesis runs?

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the file in the simulation folder and then copy it back to your IP directory when done.

If you use some form of version control such as git you can keep track of the changes you make in the simulation folder and make sure that you have copied them back.

Comment: Is this really the proper way to do it? Is this how you have done it?

I am going to start work on custom component today so this question came in my mind. I am not sure about the different ways to deal with it.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 it's how I've been doing it for 5 years or so. You'll find that Qsys/Platform Designer is a hodgepodge of bugs and annoyances, which frequently does things that make no sense (pointlessly generating block symbol files in random folders every time you save for example). My advice is to use it sparingly - build small subsystems that you connect in HDL.

Comment: For Avalon-MM, you might find [this template](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312951/how-to-select-line-to-a-14-demux-in-verliog-from-a-nios-ii-softprocessor/312955#312955) useful.